# Spring 4.3.x with OpenJDK 11

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, java-11

Spring 4.3.x is not compatible with JDK 11.
Exactly what part of the Spring code in web application running on Tomcat will not work with JDK 11?
I'm not using Spring AOP, JMS, Messaging, ORM, OXM, Test, Portlet and WebSocket.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum Spring version compatible with Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427248/minimum-spring-version-compatible-with-java-11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big jump in terms of incompatibility came with the move from 8 to 9.

You can see the tickets the Spring team had to complete to make Spring compatible with JDK 9 by using their public [JIRA issue system and looking at the jdk9/java9 labels](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17003?jql=labels%20in%20(jdk9%2C%20Java9%2C%20java9)).

For the remaining Java 11 issues, you could look at a [text search for Java 11](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16870?jql=text%20~%20%22java%2011%22).

Comment: Yes it would be a trial and error case for me to go ahead with this configuration.

Comment: You asked "*Exactly* what part of the Spring *code* in web application running on Tomcat will not work with JDK 11" so this is really a the correct answer. As you can only see what changes need to be made through the changelog and tickets.

Answer (score 1):

On the official Spring blog, they announced that Spring 4.2 would support Java 7 and 8 (it didn't change in 4.3), and they also said that Spring 5 would support Java 9.

It is implied that Spring 4 won't support Java 9.

You can follow spring updates in the https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/26/this-week-in-spring-september-26th-2017-java-9-edition

look at this duplicated post:
[Do I need Spring 5 for Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079711/do-i-need-spring-5-for-java-9)

Comment: Well I ran jdeps on Spring 4.3.x and my project source code it didn't gives anything. Yes, it works with JDK 11 but not sure about corner cases and third party libraries. Sure Spring 5.1 is fully compatible with JDK 11, it will be a hard time for us as almost 75 projects use MultiActionController 