# Intellij - Package 'javax.smartcardio' is declared in module 'java.smartcardio', which is not in the module graph but the project compiles fine

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, java-11

I'm in the process of upgrading a small spring boot application from Java 8 to Java 11. This project uses the package `javax.smartcardio`. I'm building it with maven.

The `pom.xml` basically contains the following dependencies/plugins:

- spring-boot-starter-parent (2.5.6)
- spring-boot-starter-test
- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-boot-autoconfigure
- pebble-spring-boot-2-starter
- spring-boot-starter-security
- spring-boot-maven-plugin
- maven-resources-plugin
- maven-assembly-plugin
- exec-maven-plugin

After upgrading all my dependencies and using OpenJDK11 the project compiles and runs fine (`mvn clean package`). Especially the parts using the classes from `javax.smartcardio` also work fine.

Intellij however, is highlighting all my imports of the package `javax.smartcardio.` in red.  When hovering over it, it tells me `Intellij - Package 'javax.smartcardio' is declared in module 'java.smartcardio', which is not in the module graph`. Intellij suggests to add this module via compiler options with `--add-modules java.smartcardio`. When doing so, Intellij stops highlighting the imports.

My question is now, why does Intellij highlight those imports, even though everything is compiling and running just fine nevertheless? What am I missing? Is it important to add that module when compiling? Maybe maven does something in that regard for me already? If so, which part should I lookout for?

I've read about using `module-info.java`, but came to the conclusion that using it to resolve my problem would not be the best solution. See also [Any plans for Java 9 Jigsaw (module) of Spring projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43685081/any-plans-for-java-9-jigsaw-module-of-spring-projects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue, please vote for [IDEA-259485](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-259485) Non-standard modules are not part of the class path in a non-modular module.